# How do you disable the directory listing and instead redirect it to my site with cPanel

Tags: html, url, cpanel

If search my site [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) it takes me to the directory of the site. How can I redirect it so it displays my website without having to find it through the directory?

Comment: Find the directory that your site is set to, then make sure your site is located there with your homepage being `index.html` or `index.php`. It's mostly likely your `public_html` directory or `/var/www/html` for typical CentOS web servers

Comment: Thanks mate, worked like a charm.